# MySQL query results not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying really hard to figure out why information from a database won't show up.  I think my query is failing, but I've talked to a few people and they don't know why it's not working.

Here's my code leading up to the query:

```
$getnum = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY artnum DESC LIMIT 1");

while($getnumrow = mysql_fetch_array($getnum))
{
    $theartnum=$getnumrow['artnum'];
}

$pagenum=intval($_GET['pg']);
if($pagenum==0 || !isset($pagenum))
{
    $pagenum=1; 
}
$offsetnum = $theartnum-($pagenum*15)+15;
echo("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY artnum DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET $offsetnum");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY artnum DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET $offsetnum");
```

I've went over the variables, and all seem to be working.  Echoing the query, I get:

SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY artnum DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 85

Which should work, since I've checked and the amount in articles is 85.

Much later in the code, I have:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$art_title=$row['art_title'];
$art_title_url=$row['art_title_url'];
$art_author=$row['art_author'];
$art_date=$row['art_date'];
$artnumber=$row['artnum'];
$desc=implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $row['article']), 0, 14))."...";
echo "<div class=\"big\"><a href=\"newsn.php?art=".$art_title_url."\">".$art_title."</a></div>
<div class=\"small\">".$art_date." — <a title=\"View more by ".$art_author."\" href=\"author.php?a=".$art_author."\">".$art_author."</a></div>
<span class=\"article\">".$desc."</span><br /><br />";
}
```

If I put

```
echo "test";
```

in there, I don't get that either.

My whole code is here:

http://pastebin.com/RUpb0tUG

(note:  It's not complete, I'm still working on the previous/next buttons and I can do that fairly easily)

I'm testing it [here](http://jansaviation.com/testnews.php) until it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY artnum DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 85
>
> Which should work, since I've checked and the amount in articles is
>   85.

Aha, if you have 85 records in your table, what do you expect to get from the above `select` from row number 86 to 100 other than an empty result set ??

Comment: Ohhh.  Thanks so much, I didn't realize that it was pulling from articles ABOVE 85.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance the problem lies in your "header.php" include file containing code that uses the $result variable or another variable that will screw up your later code?

Comment: Thanks, but I had previously checked and made sure that the variables used in header.php to get other information never got mixed up.